# Django static files on Heroku looping into HTTP redirect in a Safari browser

Tags: django, heroku, safari

I thought I had properly done my Django to Heroku deployment, but I'm stuck in an infinite loop of HTTP redirect and I can't figure out the way out.

Here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../static/'),
)
```

I have my stacic files stored in project_root/static.

When I ask for my CSS file through a HTTP request, I have get it right (`http://heroku-app-name/static/styles/base.css wil`l render my CSS).

But when I request my main page, I have no CSS in my Safari browser ... but everything is right in a Firefox browser.

In my index page code (in browser):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles/base.css" media="all" />
```

In my Safari's developer box I see some strange redirections:

```
http://myapp.herokuapp.com/static/styles/contracts/contracts/contracts/
[Error] Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirections (contracts, line 0)
```

Where do you think my Djando is flawed?

Comment: Do you know what's creating the requests to http://myapp.herokuapp.com/static/styles/contracts/contracts/contracts/ ?

Comment: Yes, it's the href="/static/styles/base.css" in the HTML? I have the same problem with 2 other links to static files.